# Why did the writer choose present perfect for a past situation that never happened?

Tags: present-perfect

**Interviewer**: I think a lot of people think to themselves "I should open a business," but very few have the follow-through to make it happen. Can you walk me through a quick version of how this went from an idea to opening day?

**Interviewee**: *I’ve (half) joked* that if someone had told me how hard it was going to be and how many obstacles we were going to face I would have never tried to open a business.

Why is it **have joked** and not **would have joked** because the rest of the sentence is hypothetical, if someone had told at that time but nobody told him at that time.

Comment: I think it should have been **would have joked**. I think he/she might have got it wrong while speaking in a haste.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh [speaking in haste]. No, would have joked is wrong here because that is not what the speaker wants to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the sentence below at all:

I’ve (half) joked that if someone had told me how hard it was going to be and how many obstacles we were going to face I would have never tried to open a business.

I've half joked [recently, in the past, lately] etc.

What comes **after it** is the conditional.

Another example:
I have explained to him [recently, lately, or at some unspecified time] that if he had told me the problem, I would have helped him.

I explained to him [yesterday, last week, etc. ] that if [etc.]